# Import Django settings from several files

Tags: django

There are lots of hints, why one cannot pull settings from multiple files easily, like so:

```
import base
import app1
import app2
import local
```

neither of them sees the settings from the files before and cannot modify them.

One solution is to import all the file in chain:

local.py:
import app2

app2.py:
import app1

app1.py:
import base

It's clumsy.

====

Another solution was to merge all the files into a single one.

I actually like this one. I would like to search multiple directories (OK, at least one) for *.py files, sort them by filename and import/merge them, so:

```
base.py -> 000_base.py
local.py -> zzz_local.py
```

ensure that base is first, local is last, the order of the other ones do not matter.

Is there some Django tool / framework / model, that implements this already or, at least, helps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Python's imports are not C or PHP includes. `import somemodule` doesn't inject the names defined in `somemodule` in the current scope, it loads the module (if it hasn't been already) and bind it to the name `somemodule` - then you can access names defined in the module using the qualified path ie `somemodule.SOME_NAME`.

If you want to directly bind the module's top-level names in the importing namespace, you have to either do it explicitely (`from some_module import SOME_NAME, SOME_OTHER_NAME` etc) or use a wildcard import (`from some_module import *`) but this is bad practice as it leads to hard to diagnose bugs and general maintainance hell (hint: if two of your imported module defines the same name, you'll only get the last imported one).

I've tried quite a few solutions over the years, and none of them was really satisfying, so now I just write a full self-contained settings file per environment (local, preview, preprod, prod), and use my virtualenv's post_activate hook to make the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` envvar point to the desired settings file.

For per-app default settings, I use an `app/settings` module which imports `django.conf.settings` and sets the default value if it's not already defined, then use this app/settings module (instead of django.conf.settings) in the app, ie:

```
# myapp/settings.py
from django.conf import settings

SOMETHING = getattr(settings, "MYAPP_SOMETHING", 42)
ANOTHER = getattr(settings, "MYAPP_ANOTHER", False)
```

then

```
# myapp/models.py
from . import settings

class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.IntegerField(default=settings.SOMETHING)
```

In the case of required app settings, I check for them in my app's settings file too:

```
# myapp/settings.py
from django.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.conf import settings

SOMETHING = getattr(settings, "MYAPP_SOMETHING", 42)
ANOTHER = getattr(settings, "MYAPP_ANOTHER", False)

try:
    REQUIRED = getattr(settings, "MYAPP_REQUIRED")
except AttributeError:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("you must defined settings.MYAPP_REQUIRED")
```

This scheme also allow to validate user-defined settings, ie if you expect an int and the user used a string:

```
SOMETHING = getattr(settings, "MYAPP_SOMETHING", 42)
if not isinstance(SOMETHING, int):
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.MYAPP_SOMETHING must be an int")
```